# python : Using regex to get episode

Tags: python, regex, python-re

This code works except with this fileName :

> Terkel in Trouble 2004

it should return 'null' instead the match returns 'e 200'
becouse of  :

```
      e|x|episode|Ep|^
```

and

```
    (\d{2,3})
```

How can I prevent that ?

```
def getEpisode(filename):
match = re.search(
    r'''(?ix)                 
    (?:                       
      e|x|episode|Ep|^        
      )                       
    \s*                       
    (\d{2,3})                 
    ''', filename)
if match:
    print (match)
    return match.group(1)


**EDIT:**
    test = (
    "0x01 GdG LO Star Lord  Part 1",             #1 
    "S01E01 GdG  Verso Nowhere",                 #2 
    "Wacky Races Episode 20 X264 Ac3",           #3
    "Terkel in Trouble 2004",                    #4 return None, it's ok
    "Yu Yu Hakusho  Ep 100  secret",             #5
    "Kakegurui S1 Ep11 La donna che scommette",  #6
    "Kakegurui S1 Ep12 La donna che gioca",      #7
    "ep 01 wolf's rain",                         #8
    "Toradora! 08"                               #9
)
```

Comment: Can you share some sample raw data from which you are extracting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using Word Boundaries `\b`

regex updated

```
\b(?:e(?:p(?:isode)?)?|0x|S\d\dE)?\s*?(\d{2,3})\b
```

results

```
1 ->  0x01
2 ->  S01E01
3 ->  Episode 20
4 ->  
5 ->  Ep 100
6 ->  Ep11
7 ->  Ep12
8 ->  ep 01
9 ->  08
```

Answer (score 1):

(Note that the indenting of the code in the example is not correct.)

You could refactor the alternation `|` part a bit, and then use word boundaries around the whole pattern. An example using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) that would return the first location where there is match.

```
\b(?:e(?:p(?:isode)?)?|x)?\s*(\d{2,3})\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `e(?:p(?:isode)?)?` Match `e` optionally followed by `p` optionally followed by `isode`
  - `|` Or
  - `x` Match `x`
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(\d{2,3})` Capture 2-3 digits in capture **group 1**
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Rioae/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E70WFF)

```
import re

def getEpisode(filename):
    return re.search(r"\b(?:e(?:p(?:isode)?)?|x)?\s*(\d{2,3})\b", filename, re.IGNORECASE)

episodes = [
    "Terkel in Trouble 2004",
    "eisode11",
    "episode12",
    "e13",
    "ep14",
    "EP999 this is x888",
    "  234",
    "235"
]
for episode in episodes:
    match = getEpisode(episode)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
12
13
14
999
234
235
```